# Do something if CheckBox is checked

Tags: java, android, button, checkbox

I've to do different actions with a `Button` depending of which `CheckBox` is checked, here is the code:

```
public class CostiDiImpianto extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_costi_di_impianto);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {

        double Onorario1,SpeseD1,CostI1,Iva1,Deb1,Rit1,ccp1,Netto1;
        //
        Onorario1 = 0;
        SpeseD1 = 0;
        ccp1 = 0;

        //
        EditText Onorario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Onorario);
        EditText SpeseD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SpeseD);
        TextView CostI = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CostI);
        TextView Iva = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Iva);
        TextView Deb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Deb);
        TextView Rit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Rit);
        TextView ccp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ccp);
        TextView Netto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Netto);
        final CheckBox checkBox1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        final CheckBox checkBox2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        //
        try{
            Onorario1 = Math.round(Double.parseDouble(Onorario.getText().toString())*100.0)/100.0;
            SpeseD1 = Math.round(Double.parseDouble(SpeseD.getText().toString())*100.0)/100.0;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e){
            ErrorMsg();
            Pulisci(view);
            return;
        }

        if(checkBox1.isChecked())
                    ccp1 = Onorario1 * 2 / 100;
                    Iva1 = (Onorario1 + ccp1)*22/100;
                    Rit1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+Iva1+SpeseD1)*20/100;
                    CostI1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+SpeseD1);
                    Deb1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+Iva1+SpeseD1);
                    Netto1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+Iva1+SpeseD1) - Rit1;
                    //
                    ccp.setText(Double.toString(round(ccp1,2)));
                    Iva.setText(Double.toString(round(Iva1,2)));
                    Rit.setText(Double.toString(round(Rit1,2)));
                    CostI.setText(Double.toString(round(CostI1,2)));
                    Deb.setText(Double.toString(round(Deb1,2)));
                    Netto.setText(Double.toString(round(Netto1,2)));
        if(checkBox2.isChecked())
                    ccp1 = Onorario1 * 4 / 100;
                    Iva1 = (Onorario1 + ccp1)*22/100;
                    Rit1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+Iva1+SpeseD1)*20/100;
                    CostI1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+SpeseD1);
                    Deb1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+Iva1+SpeseD1);
                    Netto1 = (Onorario1+ccp1+Iva1+SpeseD1) - Rit1;
                    //
                    ccp.setText(Double.toString(round(ccp1,2)));
                    Iva.setText(Double.toString(round(Iva1,2)));
                    Rit.setText(Double.toString(round(Rit1,2)));
                    CostI.setText(Double.toString(round(CostI1,2)));
                    Deb.setText(Double.toString(round(Deb1,2)));
                    Netto.setText(Double.toString(round(Netto1,2)));



        }




    private void Pulisci(View view) {
        EditText Onorario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Onorario);
        EditText SpeseD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SpeseD);
        TextView CostI = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CostI);
        TextView Iva = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Iva);
        TextView Deb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Deb);
        TextView Rit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Rit);
        TextView ccp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ccp);
        TextView Netto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Netto);
        Onorario.setText("");
        SpeseD.setText("");
        CostI.setText("");
        Iva.setText("");
        Deb.setText("");
        Rit.setText("");
        ccp.setText("");
        Netto.setText("");

    }

    private void ErrorMsg() {
        AlertDialog Msg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        Msg.setTitle("Errore");
        Msg.setMessage("Hai inserito dei dati non validi!");
        Msg.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }});
        Msg.show();
    }
    public static double round(double value, int places) {
        if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        long factor = (long) Math.pow(10, places);
        value = value * factor;
        long tmp = Math.round(value);
        return (double) tmp / factor;
    }
    }
```

But when I click on the clickbox the program aborts.
What am I doing wrong?

```
02-11 13:20:08.571: D/gralloc_goldfish(549): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-11 13:20:10.391: I/dalvikvm(549): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-11 13:20:10.450: I/dalvikvm(549): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-11 13:20:11.840: D/AndroidRuntime(549): Shutting down VM
02-11 13:20:11.840: W/dalvikvm(549): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
02-11 13:20:11.880: E/AndroidRuntime(549): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 13:20:11.880: E/AndroidRuntime(549): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onCheckboxClicked(View) in the activity class com.ITE.economiaaziendale.CostiDiImpianto for onClick handler on view class android.widget.CheckBox with id 'checkBox2'
02-11 13:20:11.880: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3031)
02-11 13:20:11.880: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
02-11 13:20:11.880: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
02-11 13:20:11.880: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
02-11 13:20:11.880: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-11 13:20:11.880: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-11 13:20:11.880: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-11 13:20:11.880: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-11 13:20:11.880: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 13:20:11.880: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-11 13:20:11.880: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-11 13:20:11.880: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-11 13:20:11.880: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-11 13:20:11.880: E/AndroidRuntime(549): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onCheckboxClicked [class android.view.View]
02-11 13:20:11.880: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
02-11 13:20:11.880: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
02-11 13:20:11.880: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3024)
02-11 13:20:11.880: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  ... 12 more
```

Comment: Please provide a stacktrace. BTW, you should add a listener to your checkbox, if you want to make actions depending on event

Comment: you can use radiogroup also..@user3293120

Comment: Pls share complete stack trace

Comment: can you post your error log?

Comment: provide more detailed code

Comment: As the others have asked, please [edit] your question to include the stack trace when your program aborts. Unfortunately, we don't have access to your code or development environment and cannot help you without additional information.

Comment: I've had the stack trace

Comment: I put the whole code, what i've to change?

Answer (score 2):

You should try this:

```
satView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `onClick()` function is called `onCheckboxClicked(View)`. You, however, are implementing its functionality within `public void Calcola(View view)`, so basically they don't match and Android determines the `onClick()` event function doesn't exist, so that's why you're getting that exception.

Simply rename one of them (the `onClick()` function name within your layout, or the function name) and it should work.